# Calculation expected shortfall of a distribution in R?

Tags: r, package

I tried to calculate the expected shortfall of my modified distribution function.
 I used "PerformanceAnalytics" package.

```
Fx=c(0.02469009, 0.07225651, 0.11750310, 0.16054298, 0.20148378, 0.24042788, 
0.27747265, 0.31271072, 0.34623021, 0.37811494, 0.40844464, 0.43729513, 
0.46473857, 0.49084358, 0.51567543, 0.53929622, 0.56176501, 0.58313798, 0.60346858, 0.62280765, 0.64120353, 0.65870224, 0.67534753, 0.69118102,  0.70624230, 0.72056903, 0.73419704, 0.74716040, 0.75949154, 0.77122127, 0.78237894, 0.79299245, 0.80308832, 0.81269182, 0.82182695,0.83051655, 0.83878236, 0.84664503, 0.85412424, 0.86123869, 0.86800616, 0.87444357,
0.88056703, 0.88639185, 0.89193258, 0.89720309, 0.90221656, 0.90698551, 0.91152188,0.91583701, 0.91994169, 0.92384618, 0.92756024, 0.93109317, 0.93445380, 0.93765052,0.94069134, 0.94358386, 0.94633531, 0.94895257, 0.99840417, 0.99842013, 0.99843531,0.99844975, 0.99846348, 0.99847654 ,0.99848897 ,0.99850079, 0.99851204, 0.99852273, 0.99853291,1)

library(PerformanceAnalytics)
ES(Fx,p=0.95)

ES calculation produces unreliable result (inverse risk) for column: 1 : -0.169916309516024
   [,1]
ES   NA
```

I tried not only the distribution function but also the discrete probability distribution but it gives the same warnings.
I also looked at the VaRES package. But my distribution does not belong to any specific parametric distribution.

Is it a way or a different package for the calculation of expected shortfall a distribution?

Comment: You might want to reformat some of that input as a code block, and provide some larger context for the problem so that people can reproduce your error.

Comment: To rephrase what @be_green is saying: Please be kind to the general audience and maybe provide the context of your the distribution, and what the problem you intend to solve is about in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you get the warning because you only have positive values in your data. 
You can simply transform your return values to have zero mean by subtracting the mean from the series and adding the mean back to the ES result. Make sure you actually have a return series in Fx.

Also, you need to specify the method "historical" to get your ES from your actual/empirical distribution instead of a parametric one.

See the description of the PerformanceAnalytics package for details at ETL on page 96.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf

I have fixed your code assuming that Fx is a return series and added it below.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

#Data
Fx=c(0.02469009, 0.07225651, 0.11750310, 0.16054298, 0.20148378, 0.24042788, 
     0.27747265, 0.31271072, 0.34623021, 0.37811494, 0.40844464, 0.43729513, 
     0.46473857, 0.49084358, 0.51567543, 0.53929622, 0.56176501, 0.58313798, 0.60346858, 0.62280765, 0.64120353, 0.65870224, 0.67534753, 0.69118102,  0.70624230, 0.72056903, 0.73419704, 0.74716040, 0.75949154, 0.77122127, 0.78237894, 0.79299245, 0.80308832, 0.81269182, 0.82182695,0.83051655, 0.83878236, 0.84664503, 0.85412424, 0.86123869, 0.86800616, 0.87444357,
     0.88056703, 0.88639185, 0.89193258, 0.89720309, 0.90221656, 0.90698551, 0.91152188,0.91583701, 0.91994169, 0.92384618, 0.92756024, 0.93109317, 0.93445380, 0.93765052,0.94069134, 0.94358386, 0.94633531, 0.94895257, 0.99840417, 0.99842013, 0.99843531,0.99844975, 0.99846348, 0.99847654 ,0.99848897 ,0.99850079, 0.99851204, 0.99852273, 0.99853291,1)

#Calculate reference value to check result - ES is the average of the worst X returns.
print(paste('reference value for 87.5% :' , mean(Fx[1:9])))

#Standardizing the data to zero mean
m = mean(Fx)
Fx_s = Fx-m

#Calculating ES
ES = ETL(Fx_s,p=0.875,method = "historical") + m # the old mean has to be added to the result

print(paste('calculated ES for 87.5%: ', ES)
```